# cURL PHP API call not working

Tags: php, html, api, curl

Trying to make a [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) PHP API call to [WEocr](http://weocr.ocrgrid.org/docs/WeOCR-API.html), but I can't receive a response by the API.
Here's the code I am using:

```
    $url = 'http://jimbocho.ocrgrid.org/cgi-bin/weocr/submit_ocrad.cgi';
    $header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
    $fields = array('userfile' => '@' . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0]);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

I don't know if i'm writing a incorrect syntax of the cURL  command.

Thanks in advance.

The error i'm getting:

```
Sorry!
Received a null image (0byte). See TIPS page.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your path isn't correct, try this:

```
$url = 'http://jimbocho.ocrgrid.org/cgi-bin/weocr/submit_ocrad.cgi';
$file_name_with_full_path = '/home/example/dir/sample.jpeg';
$post = array('userfile'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

---

Update based on your comments, also try this:

```
$file_new = /path/to/your/file.jpg
$cmd="curl -F userfile=$file_new \ 
      -F outputencoding=\"utf-8\" \
      F outputformat=\"txt\" \ 
      http://maggie.ocrgrid.org/cgi-bin/weocr/ocr_scene.cgi >result.txt"
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
print_r($result);
```

**Note:** You don't need to set  `CURLOPT_POST 1` if you're using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` , curl do that for you automagically.
Curl also sets the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, if the post content is an array, that's your case, no need for that too.

---

**[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)**

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file,
>   prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be
>   explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the
>   format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a
>   urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with
>   the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array,
>   the Content-Type header will be set to **multipart/form-data**. As of
>   PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option
>   with the @ prefix. As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and
>   files can be sent using CURLFile. The @ prefix can be disabled for
>   safe passing of values beginning with @ by setting the
>   CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option to TRUE.

Comment: Thank you, now I get no error but I'm not getting any response.
Might be the "outputformat"?
the API says "If you specify outputformat =" txt ", the first line of the
output data is used as the status line. The first line will be
blank upon sucessful recognition. "

Comment: What do you get from `echo $result` ?

Comment: Nothing, a blank response.

Comment: I don't know that api, what response are you suppose to receive?

Comment: in theory, should receive the text from the image. This is an API for Optical Character Recognition.

Comment: I do not work in this way, I think, php aborted the "exec" when you run a "curl"

Comment: It does not make me anything

Comment: i really sorry, but I don't know hot to help you further :(

Comment: thank you very much also, I will continue to see if I find the solution